# Creating calculated column based on another calculated column

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I am trying to achieve the following:-

```
datatable(col:string)
["one,two,three"]
| project array=split(col,',')
| project c1 = array[0],c2 = array[1], c3 = array[2]
```

This works fine. But is there any way to eliminate additional step? Basically I would like to be able to use something like the following, but it's invalid as Kusto won't allow me to create a calculated column based on another calculated column in the same line. The goal is eliminate additional step (hoping that it improves performance):-

```
datatable(col:string)
["one,two,three"]
| project array=split(col,',') , c1 = array[0],c2 = array[1], c3 = array[2]
```

I could have performed the following valid code, but then I am calling split function 3 times unnecessarily which is not very efficient:-

```
datatable(col:string)
["one,two,three"]
| project c1=split(col,',')[0] , c2=split(col,',')[1], c3=split(col,',')[2]
```

Is there any way to avoid creating additional project at the same time not giving multiple calls to the function that calculates rest of the columns?

Comment: doing things "in the same line" isn't what's going to buy you performance here - you're going to need to split the array in any case. What would help here is better data modeling - the data should be ingested as separate string columns, or at least a dynamic data type rather than a string. if you can't do this in ingestion time, you can use materialized views or update policies to do that once after ingestion rather than for each query

Comment: yes but if I am calling split function once instead of thrice , it definitely makes difference. It's sort of in memory materialization , if we can call it that. The constraint here is that we don't have choice over how it's ingested and also we can't add too many layers over source data as it would be an overkill just for getting these 3-4 calculated columns as there will be overhead cost of doing so. In the meantime I am trying to figure out if there is a shortcut way of just calling split just once and that too in the same project statement, my guess is that it's not possible, but checking

Comment: in the original example you posted you already call the split function only once, so unless you're willing to create a materialized view or update policy, that's as far as you can get. I think i'll formulate this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way in KQL to use calculated columns in the same line they were defined, but the good news is that this would not have any effect on performance anyway.

What would help with performance here is better data modeling - the data should be ingested as separate string columns, or at least a dynamic data type rather than a string.

If you can't do this in ingestion time, you can use [materialized views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-view-overview) or [update policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy) to do that preprocessing just once per piece of data rather than each time you run a query.